# Can't Wait Without A Fiber

Tags: meteor, node-fibers

**Meteor Version: 1.2.1**

**Using Base Framework from themeteorchef**

**And using a package themeteorchef:seeder**

When I tried to use the seeder package in a clean new project (without the base starter), it works fine. However in my project created from the base starter, it throws `Can't Wait Without A Fiber` Error in the part of the code that calls the Seed function.

The same thing happened to me when I try to call database functions like `find` and `insert`. I enclosed the code inside a Fiber function after adding `fibers` to the list of my `app.use` libraries in my `package.js`

Here is my `package.js` file

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'team:library',
  version: '0.0.1',
  // Brief, one-line summary of the package.
  summary: '',
  // URL to the Git repository containing the source code for this package.
  git: '',
  // By default, Meteor will default to using README.md for documentation.
  // To avoid submitting documentation, set this field to null.
  documentation: 'README.md'
});

Npm.depends({
  library: "link-to-a-github-commit",
  util: '0.10.3'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
  api.use(['ecmascript', 'templating', 'check', 'mongo', 'kadira:flow-router', 'themeteorchef:seeder', 'fibers']);


  // Load the lib directory before all other files are loaded
  api.addFiles( 'lib/constants/tokens.js', 'server' );

  api.addFiles('client/templates/library-widget.html', 'client');
  api.addFiles('client/templates/library-widget.js', 'client');

  api.addFiles('client/templates/user-folder-list-widget.html', 'client');
  api.addFiles('client/templates/user-folder-list-widget.js', 'client');

  api.addFiles('client/templates/index.html', 'client');

  api.addFiles( 'collections/LibraryUsers.js', 'server' );
  api.export( 'LibraryUsers', 'server' );

  api.addFiles('server/startup.js', 'server');
  api.addFiles('server/methods/library-team.js', 'server');

});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('ecmascript');
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('team:library');
  api.addFiles('library-tests.js');
});
```

And I am calling Seed in my server/startup.js file inside my package as follows:

```
Seed( 'Products', {
  min: 5,
  environments: [ 'development', 'staging', 'production' ],
  model( index ) {
    return {
      name: faker.commerce.product(),
      price: faker.commerce.price()
    };
  }
});
```

And I enclosed it inside Fiber as follows

```
try {
  Fiber( function() {
    Seed( 'Products', {
      min: 5,
      environments: [ 'development', 'staging', 'production' ],
      model( index ) {
        return {
          name: faker.commerce.product(),
          price: faker.commerce.price()
        };
      }
    });
  });
} catch( error ) {
  console.log( error );
}
```

after including fibers in my package file as shown in the package file above. And the error message I get is

```
[ReferenceError: Fiber is not defined]
```

What could have caused this error?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the following line before your 'Fiber( function() { ...' probably resolves that error, as it defines the 'Fiber' object that you're using:

```
Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
```

or simply this might also work, not sure:

```
Fiber = require("fibers")
```